# GCM notification coming through but need to only show the message not the whole string

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, push

This is my first attempt at Push Notifications with Android. I have the push working and receive the notification, but the message that is received is a sting.

Bundle[{android={"alert":"This is a Message"}, from=512815927951, android.support.content.wakelockid=1, collapse_key=do_not_collapse}]

All that i want to see in the notification is the alert.. "This is a Message"

Here is my GCMIntentService.java

```
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging;

public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService {
    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    private static final String TAG = "GcmIntentService";
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;

    public GcmIntentService() {
        super("GcmIntentService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        String msg = intent.getStringExtra("message");
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm;
        gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);


        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

        if (!extras.isEmpty()) {

            if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                    MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                    MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: " +
                        extras.toString());
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                    MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Completed work @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());

                sendNotification(extras.toString());

                Log.i(TAG, "Received: " + extras.toString());
            }

        }
        // Release the wake lock provided by the WakefulBroadcastReceiver.
        GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }

    // Put the message into a notification and post it.
    // This is just one simple example of what you might choose to do with
    // a GCM message.
    private void sendNotification(String msg) {
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);



        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_gcm)
                        .setContentTitle("GCM Notification")
                        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
                        .setContentText(msg);

        mBuilder.setVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 1000});
        mBuilder.setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your output, you are sending the following name/value pair - `android={"alert":"This is a Message"}`.

This means you should get the value of the "android" key, and parse the message out of it.

change

```
sendNotification(extras.toString());
```

to

```
String android = extras.getString("android");
int begin = android.indexOf(":\"");
int end = android.indexOf("\"}");
String text = null;
if (begin >= 0 && end >= begin) {
    text = android.substring(begin+2,end);
}
sendNotification(text);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I changed this and now get no text in the notification?

Comment: That worked! but I'm seeing a} at the end of the message text? Thank you so much..

Comment: @SamKing I didn't parse the String carefully enough. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Sweet! Thank so much Eran!

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
String msg = intent.getStringExtra("message");
```

to this

```
String msg = extras.getString("alert");
```

Comment: Android studio said msg is an unused variable?

Comment: Change 'sendNotification(extras.getString("alert")' to 'sendNotification(msg)'

Comment: Eran's Suggestions got it working. But thank you for your reply and help!

Comment: Cool!. Its more or less the same. :P